# I can't display member of List in c#

Tags: c#, list, console

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kelime_Türet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> Words = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                string word = CreateWord();
                Words.Add(word);
            }

            foreach (var item in Words)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
 
        static string CreateWord()
        {
            string Word = "";
            string Letters = "qwertyuıopğüişlkjhgfdsazxcvbnmöç";

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int index = r.Next(0, 32);
                Word += Letters[index];
            }

            return Word;
        }
   }
}
```

I'm able to display same member of the List, I can't display all member via foreach loop. I'm sure that i have added items to the List but i can't display them. I can see List content when i use breakpoint. The problem is when i try to display all members of the List, i only can display same member.

Comment: Dont't recreate `Random`, declare a static fied instead: `private static Random r = new Random();`

Comment: Agreed with @DmitryBychenko. After you create a static field you can use that instance to get a random value.

Comment: I don't understand what is the required output. When I run this program I get `ücqcvvanzw
fqqdzubşol
spaehpxöxs
zıdhxkjpbç
zynjbeamaw` as output. Also there is a `*` in foreach, which has to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `new Random()`. Each time you create `Random` it's initialized by system timer value.
If you routine is fast enough, you have *all* `Random r` having *same seed* and that's why generating *same values*.

```
// Don't create local Random instances, keep just one static field instead  
static Random r = new Random();

static string CreateWord()
{
    // Don't create local Random instances here, use static Random

    string Word = "";
    string Letters = "qwertyuıopğüişlkjhgfdsazxcvbnmöç";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int index = r.Next(0, 32);
        Word += Letters[index];
    }

    return Word;
}
```

Fiddle yourself

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DJCtgK

Comment: Thank you so much. I clearly understand what you mean.